# Theming Drupal Add Block form via forms API

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

Can anyone advise me on customising the Add Block form? (/admin/build/block/add)

I want to hide the "User specific visibility settings" and "Role specific visibility settings" from users. This is what i've got so far, but obviously it's not right and I can't figure out what the array is. Anyone got the experience on this?

```
function theme_add_block_form($form) {
    $form['roles']['#prefix'] = '<div class="hidden">';
    $form['roles']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    return drupal_render($form);
}
```

Thanks,
H

EDIT - perhaps I wasn't clear - I'm comforable using the various form hooks from the API, but my problem in this case is that I can't identify the array elements to use in my function. The devel module doesn't seem to act on the blocks page, and the themer popup block thing is less than clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `modules/block/block.admin.inc`, function `block_admin_configure`:

```
$form['user_vis_settings'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('User specific visibility settings'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  );

(...)

$form['role_vis_settings'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Role specific visibility settings'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  );
```

Just try to hide `$form['user_vis_settings']` and `$form['role_vis_settings']`.

**EDIT:**

Don't touch `modules/block/block.admin.inc`!! (I only was pointing where I found the form fields' names ). Hide the fields in your `theme_add_block_form`. Instead of wrapping the fields inside a div, you can write  `$form['user_vis_settings']['#access'] = false;`

Comment: I didn't intend to say that! I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: Nice one, cheers Dusan, didn't think of looking in there. And yeah don't worry I wouldn't have made my edits there, It should be clear from my post that I was creating a theme template.php function anyway. No need for the negative vote down!

Comment: points returned, never show for newbies hacking drupal code :)

Comment: Thanks Nikit, I'll write my answers more carefully. =)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6

Comment: yeah that's one option for performing the theming, but I need some help actually identifying the elements of the array to put into the function. I can't identify them using the Devel module as it doesn't appear to act on that page.

Comment: dpm($form) in hook_form_alter if you have devel (print_r if not), you'll see all internal datas for form. Add there you own form elements, and add own validate and submit calls. Learn this more helpful: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6

Comment: Tried that already - sorry should have left that in the code example :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to go. Using the http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6 as say in an other answer. You need to write this code in a costum module.

```
<?php   
 function module_name_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
      if ($form_id == 'block_admin_configure') {
       $form['user_vis_settings'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('User specific visibility settings'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#access' = FALSE,
       );
       $form['role_vis_settings'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Role specific visibility settings'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#access' = FALSE,
       );
      }
    }
```